# Warning: getimagesize() [function.getimagesize]: Filename cannot be empty in

Tags: php

I am trying to put together a script that checks the dimensions of a uploaded image.

I have a user form which has a field and browse button allowing the user to select an image and submit.

As part of the script that check the dimensions of the image I have:

```
print $_FILES['image_field']['name'];
```

This returns the name of the image "124_2493.JPG" selected but as the script progresses I get the following error:

Warning: getimagesize() [function.getimagesize]: Filename cannot be empty in

```
if(!empty($_FILES['image_field']['name'])) {
$image_info = getimagesize($_FILES["image_field"]["tmp_name"]);
$image_width = $image_info[0];
$image_height = $image_info[1]; 
}
```

As you can see "$_FILES['image_field']['name']" is not empty, it contains "124_2493.JPG".

Why is the next step producing the error.

Many thanks for your time

Comment: Read your code again. You check `$_FILES["image_field"]["name"]`, then use something else entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be :

```
$image_info = getimagesize($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]);
```

Code should be like:

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"]) && isset($_FILES['file'])) {
    $file_temp = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];   
    $image_info = getimagesize($file_temp);
    $image_width = $image_info[0];
    $image_height = $image_info[1]; 
} else {
    print "Error uploading file!";
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Hi, I could not see past the end of my nose if I tried. I never spotted that. Many thanks to you both.